# Как установить в 0 определенные биты?

Tags: c++

Имеется такая задача:

> Установить в 0 в числе А n битов вправо от позиции p, заменить ими m
>   битов числа В, начиная с позиции q.

И моя попытка решить ее, но происходит не установка битов в 0, а инвертирование

```
int A, n, p; char num[33];
  cout << "Введите число А ";
  cin >> A;
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Введите c какого бита начинать замену ";
  cin >> p;
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Скольно битов заменяем на 0 ";
  cin >> n;
  cout << endl;

  //Просто вывод числа в двоичном виде
  _itoa_s(A, num, 2);

  cout << "Число А в двоичном  виде: " << num << endl;

  //Создаю маску, одна равна единице, которая сдвинута на p-1 влево
  unsigned int mask = 1 << p-1;


  //Далее идет замена в нули, но т.к. я не знаю, как правильно это сделать, происходит инвертирование
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    A ^= mask;
    mask <<= 1;
  }

  _itoa_s(A, num, 2);

  cout << "Итоговое число: " << num << endl;
```

Желательно с подробным объяснением

Comment: `A &= ~mask;` mask инвертируется и делается побитное И

Comment: Не понял. Так вы же и используете операцию инвертирования `^=`. Если это "ваша попытка" (как вы сами сказали), то почему вы используете именно операцию инвертирования, а затем удивляетесь, что происходит инвертирование???

Comment: В условии сказано, что сбросить нужно биты "вправо от позиции p". Начинаете вы правильно - с позиции `p - 1` (т.е. "справа" от позиции `p`). Однако далее в вашем коде бит маски почему-то сдвигается *влево* на каждой итерации цикла. Почему вы сдвигаете влево, если в задании сказано "вправо"?

Comment: @AnT, "Так вы же и используете операцию инвертирования ^=" - инвертирование и XOR это немного разные вещи

Comment: @insolor: (Да, но XOR c единицей - это инвертирование. Чем автор и занимается.) XOR и "сбрасывание в 0" - это тоже "немного разные вещи". Однако в коде применен именно XOR. Я лишь исхожу из предположения, что это осознанное решение. Возникает закономерный вопрос: на чем это решение основано? И почему автора удивляет поведение XOR в этом контексте, если он сам его выбирал.

Answer (score 2):

Сталкивался уже с подобной задачей, которая звучала как-то так:

> Установить в 0 n битов в числе А влево от позиции p

```
    char buffer[33];
    std::cout << "Enter number A: ";
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;

    _itoa_s(a, buffer, 2);
    std::cout << "A in binary = " << buffer << '\n';

    std::cout << "How much bits your are want to make into '0': ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    int position = -1;
    while (position < 1)
    {
        std::cout << "From what position would you like to do it: ";
        std::cin >> position;
    }

    unsigned int mask = (1 << n) - 1;
    a &= ~(mask << (position - 1));

    _itoa_s(a, buffer, 2);
    std::cout << "\nA in binary after all transformations: " << buffer << "\nIt's " << a << " in decimal.\n";
```

Comment: Для подобных задач не нужны никакие циклы. Можно сразу сделать маску из n единиц -- `mask = (1 << (n + 1)) - 1;`, а потом один раз наложить ее, сдвинув в нужную позицию `a &= ~(mask << position);`

Comment: Благодарю за корректировку. Действительно, так было бы лучше сделать. Сейчас подправлю.

Answer (score 1):

Вот Вам способ замены конкретного бита на 0 или же на 1, как прикрутить сюда обработку нескольких битов, я думаю вы знаете)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    auto n{0b100001};
    unsigned int pos{1}; // позиция бита

    if (pos >= sizeof(n)) {
        return -1;
    }

    bool new_bit{1}; // 0 или 1 (что задать в бит на pos) bool для защиты от мусора ибо если указать что-то отличное - будет нп

    std::cout << "before : " << std::bitset<16>(n) << std::endl;

    n = (n & ~(1UL << pos)) | (new_bit << pos);

    std::cout << "after : " << std::bitset<16>(n) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно ли сделать это без использования сторонних библиотек, я новичок в  c++ и для меня это слишком запутанно.

Как-то исправить мой пример

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi тут не ни одной сторонней библиотеки ) только стандартные средства, разберитесь в моем примере и пленяйте 2 строки в вашем. Всего-то, осталось только разобраться